# Bootstrap 3 pull-right class pushing out of row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm running into a layout issue with Bootstrap 3 and could use a little help.

In my row, I have three columns like so: `[col-xs-1]` `[col-xs-10]` `[col-xs-1]`

In each `col-xs-1` there is an action button, using a font awesome icon and a button class of `btn-link`. (delete on the left, save on the right)

I can't figure out why - *especially* when the viewport is down to the `col-xs-*` size - that the rightmost column with my save button is pushed out past the row. I've tried playing with padding and margins, but no luck.

How do I prevent this from happening?

## [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nzc1y2ta/1/)

Apologies if this is a dupe - I searched and didn't see anything that was similar, but it's late and I'm tired.

EDIT: Thanks to Chandrakant Deore, here's the [final working version](https://jsfiddle.net/5gkgjxe2/1/). Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add proper **container/container-fluid** class and **row** class.
When you are nesting columns inside column add div with  **row** class.

Your button's padding is creating issue as it take some space and get collapsed down on small viewport.

Try to use col-xs-2 if there is not any issue with your requirement.

I have made changes to your code using css and mediaqueries.
This will help you

[JSfiddle Complete Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/5gkgjxe2/)

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 vertical-center col-padding-left5">
        <button class="btn btn-link padding0 ">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash text-red small-font"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 no-padding">
            <label>Some input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control no-padding">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>And</label><br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <label>More Input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 no-padding">
            <label>Some input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control no-padding">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>And</label><br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <label>More Input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
        
      <div class="col-xs-1 vertical-center col-padding-right5">
        <button class="btn btn-link padding0 " data-ember-action="1284">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-check text-green small-font"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that you are not adding container-fluid wrapper around your row. Also in small screens, you are not wrapping your content(as you are using col-xs-* classes), due to which , the width available in small devices is unable to show data inside it and hence your data(icons) are overflowing.

Add `container-fluid` div around row and reduce the size of icons in small screens

Try this CSS

```
.vertical-center {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 250px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.col-xs-1 .btn.btn-link {
  padding: 0;
}
.col-xs-1 .btn.btn-link i {
  font-size: 1em;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are facing issues basically because of the improper semantics of Bootstrap grid used by you. Find below the corrected code, it will help for sure.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Akash Kumar">
  <meta name="url" content="http://akashshivanand.com">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .vertical-center {
      display: inline-flex;
      min-height: 100%;
      min-height: 250px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Bootstrap Grid</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2 vertical-center">
        <button class="btn btn-link">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash text-red"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 no-padding">
            <label>Some input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control no-padding">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>And</label><br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <label>More Input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 no-padding">
            <label>Some input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control no-padding">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>And</label><br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <label>More Input</label><br>
            <input class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 vertical-center">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-ember-action="1284">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-check text-green"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

- As you are using fa-2x I would suggest using col-xs-2 instead of col-xs-1 as it will difficult for latter to accommodate the icons in the smaller versions of xs screens.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, but you may wanna remove or reduce column padding. Though, this might happen to screen width of below `330px` only, not sure if you really wanna to support it?

For e.g., in your case, if the row size is `300px`, the *ideal* column sizes should be:

- `col-xs-1 = 25px` (ie. 300px * 8.33333333%)
- `col-xs-10 = 250px` (ie. 300px * 83.3333333%)
- `col-xs-1 = 25px` (ie. 300px * 8.33333333%)

And the total width will *ideally* be `300px`
BUT, as the column min width is `30px` (as `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px`), therefore the total width adds up to `310px` and that's why your last column falls into the next row

Answer (score 0):

`padding:0px` to your buttons and add your buttons within `row`

```css
.btn {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.vertical-center {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-link vertical-center">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash text-red"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 no-padding">
          <label>Some input</label><br>
          <input class="form-control no-padding">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label>And</label><br>
          <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <label>More Input</label><br>
          <input class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 no-padding">
          <label>Some input</label><br>
          <input class="form-control no-padding">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label>And</label><br>
          <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <label>More Input</label><br>
          <input class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-link vertical-center" data-ember-action="1284">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-check text-green"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```